# Variable representing a class for querySelector is not defined Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nightmare

I'm not sure if this is a Javascript issue or if I'm not using Nightmare.js properly.

I'm using `.wait(className)` - then I evaluate the `innerHTML` of the `className`. This works if I add the `className` manually. However, if I want to dynamically add `className`, I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: className is not defined`

This is happening at the `.evaluate()` line. Code example below:

```
for (const [className, childCount] of pageSections) {
    it(`RENDERS THE ${className} SECTION CHILDREN`, async (done) => {
      RenderHelper.visitPage('/')  // Nightmare method from helper file
        .wait(`${className}`) // This works, dynamically
        .evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`${className}`).innerHTML)
        // Above line is where the className is 'undefined'
        .end()
        .then((result) => {
          RenderHelper.matchChildCount(result, childCount);
          done();
        })
        .catch(done);
    });
  }
```

Just to re-iterate - if I do the above but I populate the `className` manually, it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `evaluate()` is mangling the execution context which invalidates the use of `className`. To fix this, follow the guidelines in the instructions for the `evaluate()` method and pass `className` into the callback.

**Change**

```
.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`${className}`).innerHTML)
```

**To**

```
.evaluate(className => return document.querySelector(className).innerHTML)
```

The documentation follows this method:https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2

Note the use of `selector` in this example:

```
const selector = 'h1'
nightmare
  .evaluate(selector => {
    // now we're executing inside the browser scope.
    return document.querySelector(selector).innerText
  }, selector) // <-- that's how you pass parameters from Node scope to browser scope
  .then(text => {
    // ...
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried this and am getting the following error:  

Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '(err, v) => {
              if(err) return nightmare.reject(err);
              nightmare.resolve(v);
            }' is not a valid selector.


What is not making sense to me is that the selector is valid because when I hard-code the name and run the function, I can make the test pass or fail based on a very specific number (childCount)

Comment: Please see my edit. Add the return statement. If you don't return something, then Nightmare tries to evaluate the expression as a Promise and fails.

Comment: Yes got it now - although I had to add the curly-brackets before `document.query...` as in the lower example you provided from the documentation

Comment: Good catch. Glad to help.